# Need a formula to remove a variable length word in a cell that always starts with HTTP

Tags: excel, http, excel-formula

I have 1500 rows in one column that contains the work notes from help desk tickets. The contents explains how they helped a caller. Sometimes they will paste a HTTP link (not hot as it's only text) and the http link can be any length. I need to delete the ENTIRE character string making up the hyperlink.

I've tried various ISEARCH and TRIM formulas with no success.

### The contents could look like:

Caller reported trouble completing form as a requirement of their job. 
Remoted in to the callers desktop and attempted various fixes with no success. 
Eventually found a fix on an external website that corrected the issue.
https://troubleshootingfixfoundhere.com/!this_should_fix_the_issue_or_it_may_not32_40maybe

### The caller was able to fix own problem by using the steps found on that website

What formula can find and delete the entire http string, that will always be a variable length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Using Excel 2013

Comment: EXAMPLE:
01-18-2009 13:17:09 – Jim Bob (Work notes)

Request is completed. This PTASK can be closed.

01-18-2009 13:16:08 – Jim Bob (Work notes)
Request RITM9999999  created for DVR team  to create a incidents in case below two URL's have failures

https://xyz-zyx-iib.xyzint.net:7501/xyz/xyz/authenticatePin
https://xyz-xyz-iib.xyzint.net:7501/xyz/xyz/activatePin

Comment: 01-25-1942 09:26:06 - Van Shoes (Work notes)
1.disabled the services that should not be running
BDO side:
1.alarming is tuam to enable integration and email alarming is turned on.
2.An EMA service request has been created https://servicenow.xyzint.net/nav_to.do?uri=sc_request.do?sys_id=86ddb8f44ae0b9619fd for service integration.
onenote:https://bdo.wss.xyzint.net/sites/RUN/DistributedServices/ContactCenter/Support/SupportPlaybook/UCR.one#Serviceid={D0333A-900-4C8-83E-45A6B0}&page-id={8D646}&end

Comment: please update your post with the above examples plus the expected output, i.e. the string after removing the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have one substring with http then possibly:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("http",A1),IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http",A1)),LEN(A1))-FIND("http",A1)+1,"")
```

You can obviously first implement a check to see if `HTTP` is a substring.

---

Just in case you can have multiple substrings within a text containing an `HTTP` address AND you got access to [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) you could use the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("http",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))),"",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Comment: @Tinmarsh, that's because you probably don't have TEXTJOIN then. The first formula should work though

Comment: The REPLACE seems to work well until the http string is long. A 50 character string is replaced with a "" but a 250 http character string is ignored.

Comment: I think I found the issue. If there are two http strings within the same cell it only deletes the first one. If I manually remove one of them then the other is removed by the formula. Can a reiteration be included?

Comment: If you drag the formula to the right and refer to the cell to it's left. Then yes.

Comment: BINGO!  Some cells had 10 links in it so I had to drag them 10 over. Any good at VB? Would like to turn this into a macro so I end up with one result in column B.

Comment: Based on OPs examples some http links are not starting with http... and there is no clear and consistent structure of the string...I guess it would be mission impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is saved in cell A2, and the URL is followed by a space (" ").

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2;SEARCH("http";A2)-1);MID(A2;FIND(" ";A2;SEARCH("http";A2));(LEN(A2)-FIND(" ";A2;SEARCH("http";A2)))+1))
```

Comment: This resulted in a invalid formula at: (A2;SEARCH("HTTP";A2-1

Comment: You have a typo, right after "HTTP";A2-1.
There should be a closing bracket between A2 and -1

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to solve the problem. **Power Query** is available in Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions of Excel including Excel 2013.

Please note the following solution works on the assumption that **each target string contains forward lash `/` and the target string is separated by space `" "` with other words in the text**.

Therefore my solution will not work on the following cases:

> `I need to remove this www.test.com from the sentence.` My solution cannot detect the link without forward slash `/`.

nor

> `I need to remove thishttp://www.test.com from the sentence.` My solution will remove `thishttp://www.text.com` from the sentence as there is no space between `this` and the link.

nor

> `I/TerryW need to remove this www.test.com from the sentence.` My solution will remove `I/TerryW` from the sentence but not the link as the former contains forward slash "/".

If you can tolerant the above limitations, let's begin:

1. Load your data (which is a column with thousands of rows) to the power query editor;
2. Add an **Index Column** to assign a unique number to each string;
3. Use **Replace Values** function in the `Transform` tab to replace special characters such as `Line Break` or `Carriage Return` with space `" "`, repeat this step as many times as needed to make sure there is a space sit between the target string and other words;
4. Use **Split Columns** function to split the column by delimiter space `" "` and make sure to put the results into **Rows** in the advanced option;
5. **Add a custom column** using this function `=Text.Contains([Column1],"/")` where `[Column1]` is the column being splited in the last step. This function will return `TRUE` for string that contains forward slash `/`;
6. **Filter** the custom column to show `FALSE` results only;
7. Use **Group By** function to group `[Column1]` by the index column as shown below:

[image: Group By]

8. Go back to last step in the power query editor, go to the formula bar, and replace this part of the formula `List.Sum([Column1])` with `Text.Combine([Column1]," ")`, and remove the index column;

Once done, you can **close and load** the output to a new worksheet (by default).

Here is the sample data I used:

String1

```
Caller reported trouble completing form as a requirement of their job. Remoted in to the callers desktop and attempted various fixes with no success. Eventually found a fix on an external website that corrected the issue. https://troubleshootingfixfoundhere.com/!this_should_fix_the_issue_or_it_may_not32_40maybe

The caller was able to fix own problem by using the steps found on that website
```

String2

```
01-18-2009 13:17:09 – Jim Bob (Work notes) Request is completed. This PTASK can be closed. 01-18-2009 13:16:08 – Jim Bob (Work notes) Request RITM9999999 created for DVR team to create a incidents in case below two URL's have failures xyz-zyx-iib.xyzint.net:7501/xyz/xyz/authenticatePin xyz-xyz-iib.xyzint.net:7501/xyz/xyz/activatePin
```

String3

```
01-25-1942 09:26:06 - Van Shoes (Work notes) 1.disabled the services that should not be running BDO side: 1.alarming is tuam to enable integration and email alarming is turned on. 2.An EMA service request has been created servicenow.xyzint.net/… for service integration. onenote:bdo.wss.xyzint.net/sites/RUN/DistributedServices/ContactCenter/…{D0333A-900-4C8-83E-45A6B0}&page-id={8D646}&end
```

And here is my result:

[image: Result]

Here are the power query M codes behind the scene for reference only:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index","#(lf)"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each Text.Contains([Column1],"/")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = false)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Index"}, {{"Combined", each Text.Combine([Column1]," "), type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

> Actually, there are workarounds for the limitations I mentioned before. For instance, you can use `Text.Replace` function in PQ Editor to replace `http` with `(space)http` to add a space in front of each target string, and you can add an extra step to evaluate the length of all strings that contain forward slash `/` and normally the http link will have a large length than a natural word so you can eliminate the case where `/` is used in between nature words. Sorry for being lazy but given that there is insufficient sample data (and I am running out of spare time), I will not elaborate all potential solutions.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)